# Odoo Point Of Sale How to acess a Model and call methods using JS

Tags: javascript, json, odoo, point-of-sale

I want to call a custom model(kitchen.order) to create data in that model from POS using js.

but it throws an error

**TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id'**

Here is my js code (kitchen.js)

```
odoo.define('hsr_pos.kitchen_order', function (require) {
"use strict";

var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
var Model = require('web.DataModel');
var KitchenButton = screens.ActionButtonWidget.extend({
    template: 'KitchenButton',
    button_click: function(){
        var self = this;
        var val = "test";
        self.send_kitchen();
    },
    send_kitchen: function() {
        var order = this.pos.get_order();
        var lines = order.get_orderlines();
        var o = new Model('kitchen.order');
        var orders = this.db.get_orders();
        console.log(order.export_as_JSON()); 
    },
});

screens.define_action_button({
    'name': 'kitchen',
    'widget': KitchenButton,

});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got  it

```
[_.map(orders, function (order) {
            return order;
        })],undefined,
        {
            shadow: false,
            timeout: false
        }
        );
```

The code changes are as follows:

```
odoo.define('hsr_pos.kitchen_order', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
    var Model = require('web.DataModel');
    var KitchenButton = screens.ActionButtonWidget.extend({
        template: 'KitchenButton',
        button_click: function(){
            var self = this;
            var val = "test";
            self.send_kitchen();
        },
        send_kitchen: function() {
            var order = this.pos.get_order();
            var lines = order.get_orderlines();
            var o = new Model('kitchen.order');
            console.log(order.export_as_JSON());
            o.call('create',[_.map(orders, function (order) {
                    return order;
                })],undefined,
                {
                    shadow: false,
                    timeout: false
                }
                ););  
        },
    });

    screens.define_action_button({
        'name': 'kitchen',
        'widget': KitchenButton,

    }); 
});
```